# How to install RobotFrameWork with Jython For Selenium Tests?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have read http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module and other links on google but still get nothing help that how to install and how to write scripts with java -Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this guide and it's working like a charm https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/Installation